# Orange-pi zero 3 with Ubuntu22.04 trims a bit the monitor display border

Tags: display, hdmi, ubuntu-22.04, overscan

I noticed that Orangepi Zero 3 with Ubuntu22 installed, connected via HDMI to Led TV or HDMI monitor either, shows the display border trimmed a bit, let's say 10-15 pixels regardless the selected display size (1920x1080 or 1280x720 either). I could not find a way to overcome this issue that seems related to an overscan problem I do not know how to manage. Any solution / suggestion?

Comment: As always manage it at the TV. :)

Comment: Hopefully useful; https://forum.armbian.com/topic/1104-orange-pi-1-set-size-screen-solved/ and/or (for Raspberry Pi) https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=271320

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a parameter called [either] overscan or underscan. Mine on Mac is in the Display control panel - YMMV.

[image]

If you don't have one, then you need to see if your TV has a "PC mode" which should prevent overscan.

Comment: (Standard) Ubuntu doesn't have it. Some GUI software to manage ATI/AMD used to have a slider pretty much like in your MacOS picture but since they open-sourced the drivers there's no such thing or even third-party equivalent.

Comment: Hmmm… that could be 'fun'. My TV has no under/overscan compensation & I've not seen it on a computer monitor since we stopped using VGA :\

Comment: Unfortunately the HDMI monitor I am using does'nt have such a control nor the Ubuntu OS provides it on Orange.pi. Maybe I could play with xrabdr   but I do not know how..It sounds odd this problem was not raised by Orange-pi zero 3 users, I don't think it was just me to come across with this issue.

Comment: No, do go the `randr` route, it'll end badly. Furthermore Ubuntu now runs Wayland by default, not X11 (X.org). Although you probably can switch to X11 so you can use `xrandr` this will be problematic (use it only to enable *higher* modes/resolutions for those old (VGA) monitors that report themselves "wrongly") as it was never intendend to "crop". Now here's the thing: TVs may have that problem but monitors SHOULDN'T, period. The worse that can happen is not being able to select the actual native resolution and that DOESN'T happen with digital connections. What exactly are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the hints, the connection I am using is with the HDMI cable supplied with Orange-pi kit connected to a HDMI monitor Thinlerain 13,3" . The problem is there regardless the screen resolution I choose in the Orange-pi (1920x1080 or else 1280x720). Same result is there if I connect the HDMI source in my 32" LED TV.

Comment: Regarding the Thinlerain 13.3 HDMI monitor I don't think it is it to blame because when connected via HDMI to my Aspire3 A315-41 laptop the display is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I came up with the solution: After I reflashed the microSD with Debian image the screen is perfect so the problem was inside Ubuntu22 supplied by orangepi.org site.

I noticed also that among the Linux images published there just Ubuntu and Debian actually work, the orangeOS (Arch Linux) and Armbian don't probably they can fit OrangePI Zero 2 not 3 (I tried those and the boot was not starting at all leaving the red LED off).